# Vich upload bundle not saving big images in upload folder

Tags: php, symfony-3.4, vichuploaderbundle

The upload of images works fine.
But if i want to upload a big file, and i don't mean the file size, i mean the width of the file like 3024 × 4032, the bundle insert the data in the mySQL but its not saving the file in the upload folder.
Can this be a problem with the php.ini max values?
If yes, where must in put the php.ini in symfony 3.4?

THX
Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set a max value on two palaces in the php.ini:

post_max_size = 20M

upload_max_filesize = 20M

Comment: Both on 32M - any other idea?

Comment: Sorry Rajinder - my mistake. It was not the problem with the vichuploaderbundle.